# Periods and contractions and abbreviations

Tags: punctuation

My question is about "*Ms*". I wonder what the period is for?   In 'British English', as opposed to 'American English', if the abbreviation ends in the same letter as the word there is no period.   But under no known variant of English, that I know of, is there a period after a word  just because it is very short and lacks a vowel unless the word is a contraction/abbreviation.

Comment: You should consider it to be an abbreviation.

Comment: You yourself seem to implicitly acknowledge that *Mr* and *Ms* are abbreviations, thus justifying the period, at least in AmE. I don't understand what the question is?

Comment: It is indeed an abbreviation.

Comment: 'Rules' of punctuation are to a fair degree arbitrary, especially where the punctuation is not being used to indicate syntax; I have found a style guide advocating dropping full stops altogether unless confusion would ensue. This obviates the vexing question of whether or not one should double full stops etc.. / Please include references to support your claims (though style guides differ within the same country).

Answer (score 1):

As EA wisely points out, punctuation incorporates a degree of arbitrariness, so the answer will depend on the style guide you choose (or the one chosen for you). If it's any comfort, The *Chicago Manual of Style* places a period after *Ms.* and includes it as an abbreviation.  Your unease may arise from the fact that *Ms.* is not an abbreviation for any honorific in the way that *Mr.* is short for *mister*. But that doesn't bother the editors at *CMS*, so you shouldn't worry either.

Comment: It's not easy to establish/analyse usage changes over time in respect of punctuation marks, but I do know that 40 years ago I routinely included a period after **Mr.** - but for me personally, things have changed, and I'd be unlikely to do that now (I don't think I *ever* used it after **Ms**). I also rather suspect that if *you'd* been writing a century ago, you might have been likely to refer to *the editors at **C.M.S.*** (But let's not worry about that either! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The editors and I are on a nonperiodic basis. And wha makes you think I wasn't writing a century ago?